# Update rows with current item index

Tags: postgresql

I've got this table:

```
+------+----------+
| id   | position |
+------+----------+
| 1    | 38       |
+------+----------+
| 5    | 102      |
+------+----------+
| 12   | 112      |
+------+----------+
| 13   | 142      |
+------+----------+
```

And want to 'rebalance' position column as follows

```
+------+----------+
| id   | position |
+------+----------+
| 1    | 0        | (i=0 * 128)
+------+----------+
| 5    | 128      | (i=1 * 128)
+------+----------+
| 12   | 256      | (i=2 * 128)
+------+----------+
| 13   | 384      | (i=3 * 128)
+------+----------+
```

I also have scoped positions into lists like this:

```
+------+---------------------+
| id   | list_id  | position |
+------+---------------------+
| 1    | 1        | 10       |
+------+---------------------+
| 5    | 1        | 22       |
+------+----------+----------+
| 12   | 2        | 8        |
+------+----------+----------+
| 13   | 2        | 18       |
+------+----------+----------+
```

I think I need to know the index of current item in the SQL update statement, or maybe use a sub-query?

How would you go about doing this?

Comment: Can you please explain what the third table show (added an answer before I saw your update with it. Would you like a position reorder per list?)

Comment: Yep, thats it. I have a bunch of lists so I'll have to scope it down to a certain list and run multiple queries, which is fine, but if there is a better way I am all ears.

Comment: Updated the answer. Is this how it should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e58cefcacebbc09a434d54e2c1bdc2a4)

```
UPDATE mytable
SET position = s.new_position
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        (row_number() over (ORDER BY id) - 1) * 128 as new_position
    FROM mytable
) s
WHERE mytable.id = s.id;
```

Using the [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) `row_number` allows you to add a row count to your data set (your "index" if you like to call it this). It starts with 1, so I subtract 1 and multiply with 128.

---

**Updated question** (added the third table with `list_id`):

If you want to do a separate position count per list, you have to add a window frame to the window function (`PARTITION BY list_id`):

```
UPDATE mytable
SET position = s.new_position
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        (row_number() over (PARTITION BY list_id ORDER BY id) - 1) * 128 as new_position
    FROM mytable
) s
WHERE mytable.id = s.id;
```

which results in:

```
id   list_id   position
1    1         0
5    1         128
12   2         0
13   2         128
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6f95bbc2bae70677bbbea5457ed978aa)